# Setting up Continuous Integration of Protractor using Buildbot

Tags: protractor, buildbot

I have written "end to end" automatic tests for my angular website using protractor, I do know how to run the protractor test from buildbot, but **don't know how to report back the results of the test to build bot**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `protractor conf.js`, the exit status should be nonzero if one or more tests fail, and Buildbot will automatically interpret that as a failure.  In other words, the obvious approach of `ShellCommand(command=['protractor', 'conf.js'])` should work.  If you're doing something else, please give some additional information about what you've tried and what happened.